# Game score simple alghoritm

Tags: java, algorithm

Depend of the percent completion level of my game i will display some messages, i made up this pseudo code it probably doesn't work is just for you to get the point.

What would it be a "pro" way of doing the following...

```
if (successPercent == 100)
        successMessage = "OUTSTANDING";
    else if (successPercent < 100 && successPercent > 80)
        successMessage = "EXCELENT";
    else if (successPercent < 100 && successPercent > 60)
        successMessage = "VERY GOOD";
    else if (successPercent < 100 && successPercent > 40)
        successMessage = "GOOD";
    else if (successPercent < 100 && successPercent > 10)
        successMessage = "AVERAGE";
    else if (successPercent > 0 && successPercent < 10)
        successMessage = "BAD";
    else if (successPercent == 0)
        successMessage = "TERRIBLE";
```

Comment: its just good , go for it!

Comment: If `successPercent` is always going to be `100` *or less*, you can throw away all `successPercent < 100` parts. If it *might* end up over `100` -- say, because of rounding or something like that -- change the first line to `if (successPercent >= 100)`.

Comment: have you god some historical statistics about game results?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `"successPercent < 100"` part every time, because you only get to the next else if when the current if is not true.

```
   if (successPercent == 100)
        successMessage = "OUTSTANDING";
    else if (successPercent > 80)
        successMessage = "EXCELENT";
    else if (successPercent > 60)
        successMessage = "VERY GOOD";
    else if (successPercent > 40)
        successMessage = "GOOD";
    else if (successPercent > 10)
        successMessage = "AVERAGE";
    else if (successPercent!=0 && successPercent < 10)
        successMessage = "BAD";
    else if (successPercent == 0)
        successMessage = "TERRIBLE";
```

Comment: Missing the case of `successPercent == 10` (I know it's also in the question, but that's why OP asked for a professional way of doing it).

Comment: Also with this code you're never getting the message "TERRIBLE" as it always matches to "< 10", i.e. "BAD".

Answer (score 2):

I would create an enum with all possible scores. You can then call the static method getGameScore that goes through all game scores until it finds one that matches the given gamescore. This avoids a lot of duplicate code and all those nexted else if's aren't making it easy to read the code either.

Depending on what you want to do with scores that do not fall in the correct range you will need to do something else than I wrote, currently it returns the null reference if you enter a score like -1 or 101.

```
/**
 * Enum representing all possible game scores.
 * Each game score has a lower limit and upper limit.
 */
public enum GameScore {
  OUTSTANCING(100, 100),
  EXCELLENT(80, 99),
  VERY_GOOD(60, 79),
  GOOD(40, 59),
  AVERAGE(10, 39),
  BAD(1, 9),
  TERRIBLE(0, 0)
  ;

  // The max of the range for this GameScore
  private final Integer min;
  // The min of the range for this GameScore
  private final Integer max;

  /**
   * Constructs a gameScore type by specifying the range.
   * @param min
   * The minimum of the range.
   * @param max
   * The maximum of the range.
   */
  private GameScore(final Integer min, final Integer max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
  }

  /**
   * Searches a game score based on a given score.
   * @param score
   * The score for which a GameScore is searched for.
   * @return
   * Returns the first GameScore that matches the given score. This means that
   * the given score falls in the range of the GameScore.
   * Will return null if no matching GameScore is found.
   */
  public static GameScore getGameScore(final Integer score) {
    for(GameScore gameScore : values()) {
      if(score >= min && score <= max) {
        return gameScore;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
    if (successPercent == 100)
        successMessage = "OUTSTANDING";
    else if (successPercent > 80)
        successMessage = "EXCELENT";
    else if (successPercent > 60)
        successMessage = "VERY GOOD";
    else if (successPercent > 40)
        successMessage = "GOOD";
    else if (successPercent > 10)
        successMessage = "AVERAGE";
    else if (successPercent!=0&&successPercent <= 10) 
   //needs both condition since successPercent==0 is also
                                     valid successPercent <=10
        successMessage = "BAD";
    else if (successPercent == 0)
        successMessage = "TERRIBLE";
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a hash-table:**

Declare a class variable:

```
Map<Integer,String> map;
```

Initialize it once:

```
map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
map.put( 0,"TERRIBLE");
map.put( 1,"BAD");
map.put( 2,"AVERAGE");
map.put( 3,"AVERAGE");
map.put( 4,"GOOD");
map.put( 5,"GOOD");
map.put( 6,"VERY GOOD");
map.put( 7,"VERY GOOD");
map.put( 8,"EXCELLENT");
map.put( 9,"EXCELLENT");
map.put(10,"OUTSTANDING");
```

Get the score-string when needed:

```
successMessage = map.get((successPercent-10)/10+1);
```